# PHP function name on the fly

Tags: php

I have a rather stupid PHP question :D! I would like to simplify the following statement:

```
function hello_input() {
    return 'Hello World';
}

$helper = 'hello';

$helper = $helper . '_input';

$data = $helperinput();
```

The specific part I want to simplify is the adding of the _input to the $helper so it calls the right function.

I thought of something like this but it doesn't work:

```
$data = $helper. 'input'();
or
$data = $helper. 'input' . ();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: I really would like to know why you would want to simplify anything here? Sure you can write the same code that you need 2 lines for in 1 line, but seriously: does it matter? I'd call that premature optimization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func`](http://us.php.net/call_user_func), e.g. `$data = call_user_func($helper.'input');`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the whole function name into a string first.

```
$helper = 'hello';
$func = $helper . '_input';
$data = $func();
```

PHP calls this [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). See also [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: It's what his first code sample does (although variable name is wrong, but I assume that's mistake left by `$helper. 'input'();`-like experiments). And he asks how to simplify it.

Comment: I made no such assumption about his example. My answer is the corrected syntax of his two non-working attempts at the bottom of his question.

Comment: Nice. Got somebody following you around, upvoting you and downvoting me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$helper = 'hello_';
$data = $helper.'input';
call_user_func($data);
```

That should get you most of the way there.  Good luck!

[Docs here](https://www.php.net/call_user_func)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting to invoke code based on an input? You should never try to do that. That gives people the chance to execute arbitrary code. Even if you can't see quite how, it's still a potential method of attack.

What you probably want is a switch statement (or chained if statements) that match an input and dispatch the correct function.

Comment: Not arbitrary code, just funtcions in a special namespace that are designed to be called from outside. Saying this is insecure, is like saying that it's insecure to let the visitor of your site choose which php file to execute.

Comment: If they're in a special namespace, fine. But I would still say that this hints at a less-than-optimal design. Reflection (and its analogues) don't belong production code. In my opinion.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out however this is for an API and you can only make calls with several different functions (I mean if the function doesn't exist there is nothing you can do). As in "plugins"...and in the POST only defined values are allowed...